# how to analyze any text with IBM watson sentiment analysis

Tags: javascript, nlp, ibm-cloud, watson, watson-conversation

I am using IBM watsons SDK for Nodejs `watson-developer-cloud/natural-language-understanding/v1.js` and I am analyzing lines of text like 'I love Fridays and I hate Mondays' with this I have to define the targets which are `Friday` and `Monday` I wish to analyze any given line of text without setting the targets everytime

using the following code

```
 var nlu = new NaturalLanguageUnderstandingV1({
username: "",
password: "",
version: "2017-02-27",
url:
  "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/natural-language-understanding/api/"
});

nlu.analyze(
{
  text: "Iphone rocks , the android phone sucks",
  features: {
    sentiment: {
      targets: ["iphone", "android"]
    }
  }
}
```

I can use another API to find out the entities and then call this function 
but is there any other way?

Comment: What determines the targets you want?

Comment: we have to tell the targets which are being impacted by any sentiments
,here `iphone` has a positive sentiment where `android` has a negative so it could be any sentence having any entity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "entities.sentiment" sub-feature of entities documented [here](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/natural-language-understanding/api/v1/#entities).